# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html

Tags: python, django

I am creating Django User Registration Authentication – SignUpView, I dont know why i cant detect the base.html in my html file

this is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 63, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 84, in reraise
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html
[10/Aug/2020 18:44:15] "GET /SignUpView/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126471
```

this is my file tree

[image]

this is my views.py

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('loginpage')
    template_name = 'customAdmin/signup.html'
```

this is my urls.py

from customAdmin.views import SignUpView

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('SignUpView/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='SignUpView'),
    path('', customAdmin.views.Homepage, name='Homepage'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Page{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Page</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
        <br><br>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your base.html you are extending it

Comment: im going to use django base.html

Comment: is there django base.html build in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace your html to this

```
{% block 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up</title>
</head>
<body>


{% block title %}Sign Page{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Page</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
        <br><br>
        <a href="{% url 'Homepage' %}">Home</a>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```